# using nodejs, mocha, chai and sinon i would like to stub a function that is called in a route

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have a pretty simple app that is nodejs, express and mysql
I am new to unit testing and i think this app is a great way to do better.
what i am trying to accomplish ( and i think sinon is the answer) is to mock or stub *mysql.insertEventIntoDB* and *rabbit.addToRabbitMQ*

in my app i have

```
app.use('/sendgrid', sendgrid(pool, config, logger) );
```

in my sendgrid.js i have

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('../app/utils/mysql');
var rabbit = require('../app/utils/rabbitMQ');

module.exports = function (dbpool, config, logger) {
  var router = express.Router();

  router.post('/callback', function (req, res) {
    for (var x=0 ; x < req.body.length ; x++ ){
       mysql.insertEventIntoDB(dbpool, req.body[x], logger);
       rabbit.addToRabbitMQ(config,req.body[x], logger)
    }
    res.json({ status: 'OK' });
  });

  return router;
}
```

i have seen lots of example of stubs and spys but just can not figure out how to do it from these test. this is an example of one of my tests

```
it('should get an OK for delivered POST', function(done) {
 chai.request(server)
  .post('/sendgrid/callback')
  .send(delivered)
  .end(function(err, res){
    res.should.have.status(200);
    res.should.be.json;
    res.body.should.be.a('object');
    res.body.should.have.property('status');
    res.body.status.should.equal('OK');
    done();
  });
 });
```

thanks for any help/direction

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use [`sinon.stub`](http://sinonjs.org/docs/)

```
var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method");
```

To fake the `mysql.insertEventIntoDB`

```
var fakeInsertEvt = sinon.stub(mysql, 'insertEventIntoDB');
```

Then to define its behavior when this fake function is called, the parameter of `onCall` is the number of this function is called.

```
fakeInsertEvt.onCall(0).return(0);
```

---

Or according to `var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method", func);`, to fake the above function with one callback function

```
var fakeInsertEvt = sinon.stub(mysql, 'insertEventIntoDB', function(){
                                          return Math.random();
                                    });
```

In your case, it seems the second option could be better since there is `for` loop out of the `mysql.insertEventIntoDB`.